# How to implement Indoor maps

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, libgdx, indoor-positioning-system

I'm working on indoor navigation application, I need to build map with 3D overlays, in addition I need to move, zoom and rotate the map using the touches.
so when I searched about that I found google maps API and some strong libraries such as LibGDX, I worked on LibGDX with TiledMap, but I faced some problems in touches and animation, so I think the google maps API is more powerful.
can I use google maps API for indoor maps **only**, like this image:

[image]

if yes, please tell me because I'm not starting to learn it yet, else, what the best library can I use to do that and if there is good tutorials?

I will be grateful for help.

Comment: I'm not sure about your requirements, maybe you should add:
Do you use world coordinates or just local ones?
Do you want to imbed it in existing maps?
Is it necessary to update the map with other buildings later or is it static?

Furthermore which data do you have as an overlay? Do you already have a model or you first have to build that?

Comment: Yes I'm using local coordinates, and I need to use existing static tiled map, and I wanna build 3d overlay objects.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, in my opinion you have tow major choices:

- You do it appropriatly with a real mapping software. Then I would suggest you to use cityGML or indoorGML, especially when you have navigation in mind. There are tools like Esris city engine, deegree 3D or 3D city DB which might be of help. Then there are things like the ArcGIS API for building your application - but beware, the implementation on mobile devices is very buggy in my experience. There are also free Java city/indoorGML libraries that you can use, not sure on their support for Android though. 
  Meanwhile Google Maps API is supposed to support 3d as well, but I doubt it works for real 3d as I've not seen custom buildings yet. There might be a compromise using Google Earth API and overlay it with a KML indoor model. The possibillities are of course restricted with KML, on the other side, city and indoor GML is fairly heavy workload while sketchup and KML is lightweight.
- The maybe better way would be quick and dirty: Make a browser application using WebGL. Then you can use JS libraries like ThreeJS which is fairly easy. This has the advantage to be platform independent, very customizable and well looking, the Android Chrome browser supports WebGL as well. For navigation you would have to build your own logic.

Comment: Thanks @Chris for answering, but what is the extension of the map model if I used indoorGML, then how can I using exported files in Android.

Comment: indoorGML is in the end an XML file that follows the schema described by the OGC:
http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/indoorgml
You can try converting your pre-built model with FME to indoorGML.

Then either use it as a file or, more sophisticated load it dynamically from a webservice. The implementation in Android might be quite difficult though. I searched whether there are simple indoorGML viewer apps, but found none. So you would have to make most of that without references.
Especially if you are new to the GIS domain, I would recommend you go for the webGL solution.

Comment: so same problem,, I'll facing difficult and no supporting to do that!
and the webGL it is not correct solution I think because the app may be offline.

Comment: I think then your best choice would be making an application directly based on openGL, as there are many libraries and tutorials. Maybe even consider using a simple game engine:
https://android-arsenal.com/tag/2

or give the LibGDX a second try?

Comment: Thanks @Chris for replying,, I'm searching to find easy way to do that, once I found it I'll share it here :)